# Redirigir cualquier petición a una página con contenido random

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo una página con el siguiente URL
http://www.vuelabonito.com/quiz/
tiene una función en javascript que te muestra una imagen aleatoria cada vez que se recarga la página.

Quisiera que cuando el usuario escriba un link cualquiera como vuelabonito.com/quiz/Emmanuel, por ejemplo, la página a donde se rediriga me de un resultado aleatorio.

Mi funcion que genera este contenido aleatorio es la siguiente:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

enlace = new Array();
enlace[0] = '<a href="https://www.mexicodestinos.com/acapulco/paquetes/playa-suites-acapulco-all-inclusive"><img src="https://www.mexicodestinos.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Visita-Acapulco.png"/></a>';
enlace[1] = '<a href="https://www.mexicodestinos.com/cancun/paquetes/great-parnassus-resort--y--spa"><img src="https://www.mexicodestinos.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Visita-Cancun.png"/></a>';
enlace[2] = '<a href="https://www.mexicodestinos.com/san-cristobal-de-las-casas/paquetes/tours-en-chiapas--hotel-mision-grand-san-cristobal-de-las-casas"><img src="https://www.mexicodestinos.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Visita-Chiapas.png"/></a>';
enlace[3] = '<a href="https://www.mexicodestinos.com/ciudad-de-mexico/paquetes/viaja-a-ciudad-de-mexico-hotel-san-francisco-centro-historico"><img src="https://www.mexicodestinos.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Visita-CiudadDeMexico.png"/></a>';
enlace[4] = '<a href="https://www.mexicodestinos.com/guadalajara/hoteles/hotel-mision-guadalajara-carlton.html"><img src="https://www.mexicodestinos.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Visita-Guadalajara.png"/></a>';
enlace[5] = '<a href="https://www.mexicodestinos.com/guanajuato/paquetes/hotel-mision-guanajuato"><img src="https://www.mexicodestinos.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Visita-Guanajuato.png"/></a>';
enlace[6] = '<a href="https://www.mexicodestinos.com/huatulco/paquetes/paquete-a-huatulco-con-desayuno-incluido-marina-hotel--y--resort-huatulco"><img src="https://www.mexicodestinos.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Visita-Huatulco.png"/></a>';
enlace[7] = '<a href="https://www.mexicodestinos.com/los-cabos/paquetes/royal-solaris-los-cabos-all-inclusive-3334"><img src="https://www.mexicodestinos.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Visita-LosCabos.png"/></a>';
enlace[8] = '<a href="https://www.mexicodestinos.com/mazatlan/paquetes/hotel-mision-mazatlan"><img src="https://www.mexicodestinos.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Visita-Mazatlan.png"/></a>';
enlace[9] = '<a href="https://www.mexicodestinos.com/monterrey/paquetes/paquete-a-monterrey-mision-monterrey-historico"><img src="https://www.mexicodestinos.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Visita-Monterrey.png"/></a>';
enlace[10] = '<a href="https://www.mexicodestinos.com/playa-del-carmen/paquetes/viva-wyndham-azteca-"><img src="https://www.mexicodestinos.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Visita-PlayaDelCarmen.png"/></a>';
enlace[11] = '<a href="https://www.mexicodestinos.com/puebla/paquetes/viaja-a-puebla-hotel-mision-grand-ex-hacienda-de-chautla"><img src="https://www.mexicodestinos.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Visita-Puebla.png"/></a>';


aleatorio = Math.random() * (enlace.length);
aleatorio = Math.floor(aleatorio);
document.write(enlace[aleatorio]);
</script>
```

Quiseria saber como redirigir cualquier enlace para que mi funcion pueda ser ejectuada y siempre se muestre un contenido aleatorio sin tener en cuenta que nombre se escriba en la petición

P.D. Un ejemplo grafico de lo que quiero hacer se puede ver en el siguiente link

https://slack-imgs.com/?c=1&url=https%3A%2F%2Fscontent.xx.fbcdn.net%2Fv%2Ft31.0-8%2F19417593_1573017209375199_2703487081402281172_o.jpg%3Foh%3D3ea3dac2a8b3ee322ffb529f6b0b3aaa%26oe%3D59D163B9

Comment: No entiendo. ¿No es lo que haces ya?

Comment: Pero es que solo funciona en la página vuelabonito.com/quiz y yo quiero que funcione también en vuelabonito.com/quiz/emmanuel

Comment: Es como los juegos estos de facebook que te dicen escribe el link y agregale tu nombre y te da un resultado random. algo asi https://slack-imgs.com/?c=1&url=https%3A%2F%2Fscontent.xx.fbcdn.net%2Fv%2Ft31.0-8%2F19417593_1573017209375199_2703487081402281172_o.jpg%3Foh%3D3ea3dac2a8b3ee322ffb529f6b0b3aaa%26oe%3D59D163B9

Comment: ¿Y que tiene que ver el nombre? Porque lo de un contenido random ya lo estas haciendo. ¿Quieres que el resultado este relacionado en alguna manera con el nombre?

Comment: no, no es necesario que el nombre este relacionado, es solo que quiero que siga funcionando la pagina desde otra página

Comment: Porque si escribo vuelabonito.com/quiz/emmanuel... me manda el error de que esa página no existe

Comment: Entonces creo que debes expresar esa idea en tu pregunta, porque son dos cosas totalmente diferentes. En verdad, el error que estas experimentando es el de no encontrar la pagina y por lo tanto no es un error de generar contenido random ni de hacer un quiz en javascript.

Comment: Si, disculpa, es que no supe, como expresarlo, si quieres puedes editar la pregunta, pero eso es lo que quiero que sea cual sea el nombre pues exista esa página

Comment: o sea que sea vuelabonito.com/quiz/emmanuel o vuelabonito/quiz/Kenny pues funcione la página

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60930/discussion-between-kenny-barrera-and-ernesto-emmanuel-yah-lopez).

Comment: Cómo abro el chat?

Comment: aiudaaaaaaaaaaa

Answer (score 1):

Se puede hacer si por ejemplo el servidor está en `node.js` con `express`. Utilizando tu propia página podrías indicar que en cualquier dirección que comience con /quiz se mande esa página. Así:

```
app.get('/quiz', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile('quiz.html');
});
```

*Refs*:

- http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.get.method
- http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.sendFile